# Android: Why a text field in a SQLite table demands getBlob() function?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

Table Structure `Calcs` from database `your.db` (*SQLite* using *SQLite Studio*):

```
Id: Integer
Content: Text  // Type is text, not BLOB (It's a JSON string)
...
```

I know that the type in *SQLite* it's just a suggestion, but I've verified the type outside *SQLite Studio* (See **PS** in the end)

My *Kotlin* code

```
...
your = File(this.filesDir, "your.db").absolutePath
val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(your,null,  
             SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
val c = db.query("Calcs", arrayOf("Conteudo"), "Id=?", 
        arrayOf(1), null, null, null)
val stat = c.moveToFirst()
if (! stat)   exitApp(this)
val conteudo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Conteudo"))
...
```

Error: `SQLite exception unable to convert BLOB to string`

The solution for my problem was really weird. I've replaced the last source line for:

```
val blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Conteudo"))
var conteudo = String(blob)
conteudo = conteudo.substring(0,conteudo.length-1)
```

It works because after I've used the function `fromGSon()` from *gson* package to transform a *JSON* string in a *Kotlin* class filled with my data.

First it loads a `byte array` with 0 extra byte added in the end of the string. So the length is equal to original field in my SQLite table (I've checked with `length` *SQLite* function) plus 1.  So I've needed to take this 0 out from string before I can use in a *JSON* transformation.

**Questions:**

*1)* Why a column declared as `Text` in SQLite needs a `getBlob()` function in *Kotlin*?
*2)* Why it brings an extra 0 byte in the end?

**PS:**:

Since this could be a quirk from *SQLite Studio*, I've decided look at *SQLite* command line utility (My *SQLite* is updated and my system is *Windows*):

I've filled the field `conteudo` using a text file `your.txt` (2723 characters) that stores the content, with the command:

```
UPDATE my_table set my_column=readfile('c:\data\android\your.txt') 
 where id=1;
```

So I went to the folder `C:\Data\Android` that holds `your.db` and ran *SQLite*:

```
C:\Data\Android> SQLite3 your.db
```

Then I've run the following commands:

```
.header on
.mode column
.pragma table_info('calcs');
```

It showed.

```
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --
0           Id          INTEGER     0                       1
1           Nome        TEXT        0                       0
2           Conteudo    TEXT        0                       0
3           Cont2       BLOB        0                       0
```

The last but not the least:

The command `select typeof(conteudo) from calcs` also has returned `text`.

Below I put 2 images to check my claims,
First from `SQLite Studio` structure:

[image: SQLite Studio image]

Second image is from my `Kotlin` code
[image: Kotlin piece of code]

My final piece of code in *Kotlin*, after all checks;

```
val your = fullPath(this,"your.db")
val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(your,null, 
          SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
val c = db.query("Calcs", arrayOf("Conteudo",
       "Length(Conteudo) As Len"), "Nome=?",
       arrayOf(calcActive), null, null, null)
val stat = c.moveToFirst()
if (! stat) exitApp(this)
val blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Conteudo"))
val len = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Len"))
val len2 = blob.size
val char =blob[len2-1]
val result = "Len $len, Len Blob: $len2, $char"
```

The `result` is `LEN 2273 LEN BLOB 2274,0`

**UPDATE 2**:

Now, suddenly `getStrings` works again for me. I swear that I don't edit the field type. In the middle, I just added a dummy field for testing. However it's clear for me that `getBlob` should throw an exception and not silently returns a byte array with 0 added in the end.

Comment: The zero at the end sounds like a null termination character.  Languages like C (Sqlite is written in C) define strings as an array of char with a null termination character following the end of the string.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Kotlin issue. If you could edit your question and provide the complete stack trace, that may make it easier for us to track down where the message is coming from.

Comment: OK, what data type is the corresponding field in your database?

Comment: `Text` type, no doubt about it. I've created in `SQLite Studio`. I will check now in `SQLite3` in command line.

Comment: SQLite doesn't really use types with columns, though. Those are hints, and a given value does not necessarily have to match it. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

Comment: SQLite command `.schema calcs` shows `CREATE TABLE Calcs (Id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, Nome TEXT UNIQUE, Conteudo TEXT, Cont2 BLOB);`

Comment: SQLite is written in `C`, but `Select length(cont2) From Calcs`  show `2723` characters and byte array in Kotlin has `2724` with 0 added in the end.

Comment: How are you storing this value in the database?

Comment: using 

`UPDATE calcs set conteudo=readfile('your.txt') where id=1;`

In `SQLite Studio`.  I have a file called `your.txt` with the same `2723` characters.

Comment: Outside `SQLite Studio`, using  `C:\Data\Android\> SQLite3 your.db` I run 
`.header on   .mode column      pragma table_info('calcs')`    and it shows. `conteudo` like a string field.

Comment: If the `readfile()` in SQL Studio is the same as the one in the standard sqlite3 shell, it returns a blob.

Comment: Test for yourself with `SELECT typeof(conteudo) FROM calcs WHERE id = 1` though.

Comment: Ok, the result is `typeof(conteudo) = text`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195310/discussion-between-paulo-buchsbaum-and-shawn).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to investigate how you are inserting or updating the column. That is that SQLite allows you to store any type of data in any column, irrespective of the type you use use to define the column with. Perhaps have a read of [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

e.g. try running this in SQLite Studio :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS type_affinity_example;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS type_affinity_example (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- <<<<<<<< MUST BE INTEGER VALUE ELSE INVALID DATATYPE
    col1 rumplestiltskin,
    col2 BLOB,
    col3 INTEGER,
    col4 NUMERIC,
    col5 REAL,
    col6 REALINT, -- because of rule 1 will be INTEGER type affinity NOT REAL!!!!
    col7 TEXT
);

INSERT INTO type_affinity_example (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7) VALUES

    (1.3456,1.3456,1.3456,1.3456,1.3456,1.3456,1.3456),
    ('A','A','A','A','A','A','A'),
    (1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    (x'0102',x'0102',x'0102',x'0102',x'0102',x'0102',x'0102')
;

SELECT 
    rowid,
    *,
    typeof(id) AS ctypeid, 
    typeof(col1) AS ctype1, 
    typeof(col2) AS ctype2, 
    typeof(col3) AS ctype3, 
    typeof(col4) AS ctype4,  
    typeof(col5) AS ctype5, 
    typeof(col6) AS ctype6, 
    typeof(col7) AS ctype7  
FROM  type_affinity_example
```

Which produces :-

[image]

- Navicat was used (the various SQLite management tools have their own way off handling blobs)

**As such it is highly likely that you are inadvertently storing the data as a BLOB.**

It could just be that you've inadvertently swapped columns by using **cont2** instead of **conteudo** and thus stored a blob at some time.

It could be because of wherever you do *First it loads a byte array with 0 extra byte added in the end of the string.* and you are then binding a byte array rather than a string when inserting/updating.

I'd suggest not using `SELECT typeof(conteudo) FROM calcs WHERE id = 1` as this only checks the one row but rather run :-

```
SELECT typeof(conteudo) FROM calcs;
```

Or

```
SELECT Id,typeof(conteudo) FROM calcs WHERE typeof(conteudo) = 'blob';
```

Another thought is that you are adding a byte when inserting/updating but that that is not a valid character when extracting and thus that it it then converted at a BLOB type (not tried to see if that happens but it could be within the SDK that it fails to convert and assumes unconvertable character equates to a BLOB), perhaps try padding the length with a character rather than a byte.

## Additional

You might be interested in the following experiment but it may explain the magical extra byte :-

Here's the DBHelper :-

```
class DBHelper(context: Context?) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION) {

    internal var mDB: SQLiteDatabase

    init {
        this.mDB = this.writableDatabase
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(crt_mytable_sql)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {}

    fun insert(nome: String, conteudo: String, cont2: ByteArray): Long {
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COl_MYTABLE_NOME, nome)
        cv.put(COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO, conteudo)
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_CONT2, cont2)
        return mDB.insert(TBL_MYTABLE, null, cv)
    }

    companion object {
        val DBNAME = "your.db"
        val DBVERSION = 1
        val TBL_MYTABLE = "calcs"
        val COL_MYTABLE_ID = "Id"
        val COl_MYTABLE_NOME = "Nome"
        val COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO = "Conteudo"
        val COL_MYTABLE_CONT2 = "Cont2"

        internal val crt_mytable_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_MYTABLE + "(" +
                COL_MYTABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COl_MYTABLE_NOME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO + " TEXT, " +
                COL_MYTABLE_CONT2 + " BLOB " +
                ")"
    }
}
```

and the activity :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal var myTestString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var mDBHlpr = DBHelper(this)
        val sb = StringBuilder().append("{")
        for (i in 0..0) {
            sb.append(myTestString)
        }
        sb.append("}")
        mDBHlpr.insert("BLAH", sb.substring(0, sb.length - 1),byteArrayOf(0))
        val columns = arrayOf(DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO,"length(" + DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO + ") AS len")
        val csr = mDBHlpr.writableDatabase.query(DBHelper.TBL_MYTABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null)
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("EXTRACTED",
                    csr.getString(
                    csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO)) + " Length is " +
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("len"))
            )
            val barray = csr.getBlob(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COl_MYTABLE_CONTEUDO))
            Log.d("BALEN","Length of the byte array is " + barray.size)
            val sb2 = StringBuilder()
            for (b in barray) {
                sb2.append((b and (0xFF).toByte()).toChar())
            }
            Log.d("VIABLOB",
                    sb2.toString() + " Length is " +
                            csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("len"))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

When run for the first time it produces :-

```
2019-06-21 15:25:32.633 D/EXTRACTED: {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 Length is 37
2019-06-21 15:25:32.633 D/BALEN: Length of the byte array is 38
2019-06-21 15:25:32.633 D/VIABLOB: {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890�� Length is 37
```

i.e. extracting TEXT as a blob and converting it isn't just plain sailing (same with Java, it's not a Kotlin issue nor I suspect an SQLite issue but I suspect an SDK issue)

Comment: I check many times using SQLite3 command utility and my table `calc` (that I've created for testing only) has just one record. I already have deleted the column `cont2` (that I've used for testing blob field).

Comment: I add an `SQLite Studio` image in the final of the question for you check my claims.

Comment: And a piece of `Kotlin` code, using `Conteudo`field

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum I would pay little attention to SQlite Studio it may have it's way of handling the unexpected. Although you might try `SELECT hex(substr(conteudo,length(conteudo),1))  FROM calcs`

Comment: My project now is using the weird solution with `getBlob()` for reading a string field. and other weird stuff that needs strip the byte 0 in the end of field value, that don't exist in the table, neither in the text file that gave origin to field value.

Comment: I've run your code in `SQLite`  command line utiliy: `7D`  that is "}", as expected. It's the last character of a valid JSON string.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum  now try it in the App is it still 7D? If so how is the App's db different to the SQLite Studio. Perhaps copy the DB from the App and open it in Studio.

Comment: All checks above I've also ran  inside official `SQLite 3` command line utility, just in an updated version: `3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53`

Comment: Ok, I will run now the app in my cell phone for test it

Comment: The same stuff, 0 byte in the end, one additional char, but I test again and now `getString` works! I don't understand. Anyways, I think that `getBlob` should throw an exception.

Comment: The explanation that getString now works should be that I've  run `Invalidate Caches/Restart` in my updated `Android Studio`. Sometimes my system don't recognize the `default activity` or gives an error in a simple button id and this simple procedure solve it.

Comment: @mike_T, Unfortunately, the mistake has again happened. I changed the data but not the structure. The code is the same. I re-checked the structure with the pragma in the `SQLite` command line. I checked `MD5`, I made sure the `JSON` to and from is correct. However, `getString` again does not work on the `SQLite` String type of a field with 2730 characters. And `Blob` comes back with 1 more character (# 0).

Comment: My code using a obscure `Kotlin` function is

`val conteudo = String(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Conteudo"))).removeSuffix(0.toChar().toString())`. It strips the 0 byte when the string ends with it